# Trying to concatenate LINQ column values, Not sure where the LINQ error is?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to concatenate a 2 column values. Should be simple, but my LINQ is incorrect it seems:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StdOrgUsers
                              .Where(r => r.IsAccountOwner == true)
                              .First(r => new {r.Firstname + " " + r.Lastname }))
```

I am getting this error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0746: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Must be something to do with:

```
new {r.Firstname + " " + r.Lastname }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't declare anonymous type inside `First` you need is:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StdOrgUsers
                                  .Where(r => r.IsAccountOwner == true)
                                  .Select(r => new { FullName = r.Firstname + " " + r.Lastname }))
                                  .First();
```

Also specify a property name for your anonymous type `FullName`, since you are concatenating two properties.

For the error:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions.

You don't need anonymous type , a simple concatenated string would be enough like:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StdOrgUsers
                                  .Where(r => r.IsAccountOwner == true)
                                  .Select(r => r.Firstname + " " + r.Lastname)
                                  .First();
```

Comment: Actually I got an error with this:... CS0746: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access. I copied and pasted your code.

Comment: @SamJolly, are you sure you have specified the property name `FullName` , like in the code `.Select(r => new { FullName = r.Firstname + " " + r.Lastname }))` ?

Comment: OK, done that. Now getting: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: @SamJolly, In that case you don't need anonymous type at all, simply do : `.Select(r => r.Firstname + " " + r.Lastname )`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an anonymous type to concatenate two strings:

`@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StdOrgUsers.Where(r => r.IsAccountOwner == true).Select(r => r.Firstname + " " + r.Lastname).First())`